# Using Intellectual property to develop software and making money off of it

Tags: intellectual-property

Me and my team of developers are about to finish a turn based game based on an existing franchise.

We are deciding between Dragon Ball or League of Legends. We are using their intellecual property.

We are from Mexico and have no plans on charging for the game or any of its content, its gonna be free for everyone.

We are planing on "gifting" a different design on the users interface that affects in no way the gameplay to the users that donate us a scpecific amount of money.

What are our posibilities here? how much can we get away with? Is there any advantage on us being on México? Is there any advantage on picking any either Dragon Ball or League of legends because of the country they are in? Can they stop us from doing it?

This is hypothetical, how easy is it to abuse the current sistem in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are our possibilities here?

You could be sued for damages in Mexico, the country of origin of the copyright or any of the other signatories of the Berne Convention. You could also be charged with a criminal offence but that is less likely.

> how much can we get away with?

Not a legal question. What you are proposing is illegal - how likely your getaway plan is to work is not for me to say.

> Is there any advantage on us being on México?

No

> Is there any advantage on picking any either Dragon Ball or League of legends because of the country they are in?

No

> Can they stop us from doing it?

Yes